# How do I replace lines in a file using data contained elsewhere in the same file?

Tags: python, algorithm, io

Let's say I have a file called 'Food' listing the names of some food, and their prices. Some of these items are raw ingredients, and others are made from different amounts of these- for example i might manually list the price of eggs as 1 and find that the omelette has a default price of 10, but then find that an omelette will only need 5 eggs, so i would need the program to read the price of eggs, find the line containing the omelette, and replace it with "omelette: " + str(5*eggs). I may also need to add extra ingredients/ items of food e.g. a pile of omelettes which is made from 5 omelettes. the basic goal would be to make it possible to just edit the value of eggs, and the value of omelette and pileofomelettes to update. I've started the code simply by creating a list of the lines contained within the file.

```
with open("Food.txt") as g:
    foodlist=g.readlines()
```

The file 'Food.txt' would be in the following format:

```
eggs: 5
omelette: 20
pileofomelettes: 120
```

etc...
and after the code runs it should look like

```
eggs: 5
omelette: 25
pileofomelettes: 125
```

I would  code the relations manually since they would be so unlikely to ever change (and even if they did it would be fairly easy for me to go in and change the coefficients)

and would be read by python in its list format as something like

'['egg 2\n', 'flour 1\n', 'butter 1\n', 'sugar 3\n', 'almond 5\n', 'cherry 8\n']'

I have searched for search/replace algorithms that can search for a specific phrase and replace it with another specific phrase, but i don't know how i'd apply it if the line was subject to change (the user could change the raw ingredient values if he wanted to update all of the values related to it). One solution i can think of involves converting them into a dictionary format, with them all listed as a string-integer value pair, so that i could just replace the integer part of the pair based on the integer values stored within other string-integer pairs, but, being inexperienced, I don't know how i'd convert the list (or the raw file itself, even better) into a dictionary.

Any advice on how to carry out steps of this program would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT- in the actual application of the program, it doesn't matter what order the items are listed in in the final file, so if i listed out all the raw ingredients in 1 place and all of the composite items in another (With a large space in between them if more raw items need to be added) then i could just re-write the entire second half of the file in an arbitrary order with no problem- so long as the line position of the raw ingredients remains the same.

Comment: could you include the two source files?

Comment: does this chain throught? What if I define a pile of omelettes?

Comment: I've done this food example to help me apply it to an actual example in much the same format- And yes i would like to be able to define a pile of omelettes perhaps at a later stage and simply copy some code from earlier on the program and simply change the arguments it contains to work for a pile of omelettes

Comment: There may also be things in the list that require you to have the values of multiple ingredients e.g. cake = flour+butter

Comment: The problem here is you need some sort of relational model or you will have to hardcode the eggs relationship to the omelette

Comment: I don't expect this program to be short at all- in the real example i'm doing (Which is working out the prices of items in Minecraft based on what they're crafting ingredients are)- I will have to write out a different piece of code for all 173 items i'm going to write for (or at least, i expect to have to)- i just need to know how to do it for 2 or so items so i can get going. I will look up the relational model as I go along and write it in, just used the omelette as an example of a simple relation.

Comment: ok can you give me your expected output of the example you have in the original post?

Comment: Is there a point in your file that says `5 eggs -> 1 omelette`, or will you be hardcoding that?

Comment: @Teepeemm I will be hardcoding that ,  at Cody Bouche i expect the omelette line to become 'omelette: 25' and the pile of omelettes line to become 'pileofomelettes: 125'

Comment: in the context of my goal, the recipes aren't going to change, i'll just hardcode all of the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I would suggest make a relations text file which you can parse in case you think the relations can later change, or just so that your code is easier to read and mutable. This can be then parsed to find the required relations between raw ingredients and complexes. Let it be "relations.txt" , and of the type:

```
omelette: 5 x eggs + 1 x onions
pileofomelettes: 6 x omelette
```

Here, you can put arbitrary number of ingredients of the type:

> complex: number1 x ingredient1 + number2 x ingredient2 + ...

and so on.
And your food.txt contains prices of all ingredients and complexes:

```
eggs: 2
onions: 1
omelette: 11.0
pileofomelettes: 60
```

Now we can see that the value for pileofomlettes is intentionally not mapped here correctly. So, we will run the code below, and also you can change numbers and see the results.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
''' This program takes in a relations file and a food text files as inputs
and can be used to update the food text file based on changes in either of these'''

relations = {}
foodDict = {}

# Mapping ingredients to each other in the relations dictionary
with open("relations.txt") as r:
    relationlist=r.read().splitlines()
    for relation in relationlist:
        item, equatedTo = relation.split(': ')
        ingredientsAndCoefficients = equatedTo.split(' + ')
        listIngredients = []
        for ingredient in ingredientsAndCoefficients:
            coefficient, item2 = ingredient.split(' x ')
            # A list of sets of amount and type of ingredient
            listIngredients.append((float(coefficient),item2))
        relations.update({item:listIngredients})


# Creating a food dictionary with values from food.txt and mapping to the relations dictionary
with open("food.txt") as g:
    foodlist=g.read().splitlines()
    for item in foodlist:
        food,value = item.split(': ')
        foodDict.update({food:value})
    for food in relations.keys():
        # (Raw) Ingredients with no left hand side value in relations.txt will not change here.
        value = 0.
        for item2 in range(len(relations[food])):
            # Calculating new value for complex here.
            value += relations[food][item2][0]* float(foodDict[relations[food][item2][1]])
        foodDict.update({food: value })

# Altering the food.txt with the new dictionary values 
with open("food.txt",'w') as g:
    for key in sorted(foodDict.keys()):
        g.write(key + ': ' + str (foodDict[key])+ '\n')
        print key + ': ' + str(foodDict[key])
```

And it comes out be:

```
eggs: 2
onions: 1
omelette: 11.0
pileofomelettes: 66.0
```

You can change the price of eggs to 5 in the food.txt file, and

```
eggs: 5
onions: 1
omelette: 26.0
pileofomelettes: 156.0
```

Comment: I suppose i could make a relations file, but since there's the problem of some items that may require a certain amount of 1 item and a certain amount of another, so I think i'll just go for the simpler option of manually coding. Instead, if i wanted to change the coefficients used to work out the updated values i think i'd just go in and edit the program itself, just as quick as going into a seperate .txt file if i use Ctrl + F.

Comment: You could easily modify this to add a '+' for all the commodities that go into your mixture, and parse the file. It may be a bad idea to hard-code these numbers because it will impossible to debug your code!

Comment: While i do know it would be bad practice, i won't be using a separate file for the relations, I've also highlighted that now i won't need to do any search and replacing- So all i really need to know is how to look up the values in the dictionary and rewrite the file based on that (Sorry you went through the effort of writing that code :( ) i'll have a look at this again tomorrow and see if i can condense the problem to something with a little less ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, I read this now, but I made the change I was referring to. I hope this new change above already works for you.

Comment: Works now, just added some parentheses by that last print statement, will now start work on making it work on the real example :)

Comment: Sure, you can write back here if there is trouble, be sure to mark up the answer if you think it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

How does your program know the components of each item?  I suggest that you keep two files: one with the cost of atomic items (eggs) and another with recipes (omelette <= 5 eggs).

Read both files.  Store the atomic costs, remembering how many of these items you have, *atomic_count*.  Extend this table from the recipes file, one line at a time.  If the recipe you're reading consists entirely of items with known costs, then compute the cost and add that item to the "known" list.  Otherwise, append the recipe to a "later" list and continue.

When you reach the end of both input files, you will have a list of known costs, and a few other recipes that depended on items farther down the recipe file.  Now cycle through this "unknown" list until (a) it's empty; (b) you don't have anything with all the ingredients known.  If case (b), you have something wrong with your input: either an ingredient with no definition, or a circular dependency.  Print the remaining recipes list and debug your input files.

In case (a), you are now ready to print your Food.txt list.  Go through your "known" list and write out one item or recipe at a time.  When you get to item [atomic_count], write out a second file, a new recipe list.  This is your old recipe list, but in a useful top-down order.  In the future, you won't have any "unknown" recipes after the first pass.

For future changes ... don't bother.  You have only 173 items, and the list sounds unlikely to grow past 500.  When you change or add an item, just hand-edit the file and rerun the program.  That will be faster than the string-replacement algorithm you're trying to write.

In summary, I suggest that you do just the initial computation problem, which is quite a bit simpler than adding the string update.  Don't do incremental updates; redo the whole list from scratch.  For such a small list, the computer will do this faster than you can write and debug the extra coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not really sure what you are asking but this is what I came up with...

```
from collections import OrderedDict

food_map = {'omelette': {'eggs': 5, 'price': None}, 'pileofomelettes': {'eggs': 25, 'price': None}, 'eggs': {'price': 5}}

with open('food.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

data = OrderedDict([(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in [x.split(': ') for x in data]])

for key, val in data.items():
    if key == 'eggs':
        continue
    food_rel = food_map.get(key, {})
    val = food_rel.get('eggs', 1) * food_map.get('eggs', {}).get('price', 1)
    data[key] = val

with open('out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    data = '\n'.join(['{0}: {1}'.format(key, val) for key, val in data.items()])
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Yes i think that OrderedDict function will be very useful- will it return something along the line of {"eggs" : 5 , "omelette" : 20 , "pileofomelettes" : 120 } ? Because if that's the case then all i'm looking to do is write lots of individual statements that just (the relations of which i will hard-code) update the values stored in the dictionary